# Dimension of Model B rev 2 mounting holes

Tags: pi-models

I want to make some laser cut mounting brackets for some Model B rev 2 (*NOT* model B+) - this is the Raspberry Pi with 2 mounting holes.

I can find a pdf with a cutting template but no 2d diagram or .dxf or .svg with the mounting holes and board outlines to scale.

Does anyone have a source for the dimensions?

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/30083/19949 addresses the diameters albeit not the position of the holes if that is what you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

[Raspiworld.com](http://www.raspiworld.com/images/other/drawings/Raspberry-Pi-1-Model-B.pdf) has a pretty solid looking dimensional drawing on their Raspberry Pi pages:

[image: Raspi.com drawing of a Raspberry Pi model B]

If you have access to the necessary software (Solidworks from the looks of things), you might also want a look at some of [GrabCAD's](https://grabcad.com/library?page=1&time=all_time&sort=recent&query=raspberry%20pi%20%22model%20b%22) user submitted models. There are a few [here](https://grabcad.com/library/raspberry-pi-b-1), [here](https://grabcad.com/library/raspberry-pi-model-b) and [here](https://grabcad.com/library/raspberry-pi-model-b-512mb-ram-uk-model-1). These can vary a little in their accuracy, so take them with a pinch of salt.